# f deletes its self behind a string unable to create a f string

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Unable to create a f string in visual studio code**

I'm unable to create a f string in visual studio

https://giphy.com/gifs/FqCGQXiV6LObgFWHsV (GIF)

every time I place a f behind a string within a print() it will automatically delete infinitely. this is strange behavior I've never been in this situation before. I would upload a picture but since the f always deletes there would be no sense and showing this also if the pinchers would highlight green I would share a picture but this also does not change.

- unable to place f behind strings within a print function doing so causes it to be deleted

any help on this would be greatly appreciated! A work around is to just concatenate your
variables/constants but this is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out turns out there needs to be a variable or constant inside the
pinchers first in order to put the f! Make sure to put your variable/constant name first hope this helps!